# Performing a search on an NSArray from a UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm trying to perform a search on some results from a JSON feed that have been loaded into an NSArray called tableData and then displayed in a UITable.

The searchResults NSArray has been declared the .h file. The problem is that at the moment searchResults are empty and output nothing to the console. I'm not sure why...

I'm wondering if there's something missing from the

```
searchResults = [tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

line of code below

thanks for any help.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    NSLog(@"searchResults: %@", searchResults);

    NSLog(@"tableData results: %@", tableData);

}
```

Comment: Your tableData is just an NSArray of NSStrings?

Comment: no, the data is an NSDictionary like for each record returned: table results are {
    cat = "Pacchetti Vacanze";
    city = "*";
    coords =     {
        lat = "45.69769";
        lng = "9.21534";
    };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a field called 'cat' in your Dictionary, instead of having the predicate look in SELF, it should look in SELF.cat.

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.cat CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
```

If you still need to check other fields contained within the object, you can create a compound predicate. Details on Predicates can be found in [Apple's Predicate Programming Guide.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace [cd] -> [c]:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.youProperty contains[c] %@", searchString];
```

like[cd] means “case- and diacritic-insensitive like.”